# What is a good number of sentient species?

Tags: internal-consistency, creature-design

In a world similar to Earth where multiple species are able to achieve human-like sentience, what is the realistic limit for the number species that will actually achieve it concurrently?

Comment: By seeing what happens in Earth... One, or none...

Comment: This question may be too vague. It depends largely on when the species became sentient (one after the other or all at once), and what the environmental roles of these species are (carnivore, herbivore). Perhaps, a "realistic" number is 1, the first ones to gain sentience are hunter predators and kill out any other species that gains sentience.

Comment: I edited your question to confine it to concurrent sentient species. Please revert if you want the number of species that could occur through the lifetime of the planet without necessarily existing at the same time.

Comment: What's the different it will be only 1 left in the end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The archaeological record supports the fact that there were multiple hominid species generally coexisting in the distant past. Homo Sapiens even interbred to a limited extent with both the Neanderthal peoples and the Denisovans, leaving a record in our own genetic material.

Contrary to some speculation, there is no evidence that Homo Sapiens directly destroyed the other hominid species through war or violence. The Neanderthals were highly adapted to an ice age climate and lifestyle, living in tiny bands scattered across the vast landscape. Homo Sapiens is thought to have been able to spread into the unclaimed spaces, and being more numerous, eventually have occupied all the available niches, outnumbering their cousins and essentially consuming all the resources the others needed. (What happened to the Denisovans is less clear, since they have left so little in the fossil record).

To me this suggests that so long as the sentient species (plural) do not overlap in the ecological niches they occupy, they will not outcompete each other for resources during the long climb to sentience. If their ecological niches overlap too much, then the species which is more adaptable will be able to drive the other to extinction before either reaches a technological level beyond the stone age.

So it may be possible that there could be several sentient terrestrial species on a planet, and one or more marine species as well. The actual number would have to depend on how many distinct and non overlapping biomes exist for each species to evolve and develop sentience. As they grow in numbers and power, they will become aware of the other species as the strange spirits which live in the edge of (environment x) and who seem to talk and know how to make peculiar and interesting things that they often trade for unusual objects that our people make.

If this leads to a sort of mutual interaction based on trade, or destructive struggles for resources at the edges of the biomes will be determined by many random factors of environment, history and culture.

Answer (score 2):

**It depends on how you define sentience.**

If it's similar to Earth and the way the scientific community is [currently leaning](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/animal-emotions/201306/universal-declaration-animal-sentience-no-pretending) on how to define sentience, then the answer is "thousands".

If you have a financial stake in whether animals have rights based on sentience, or a human superiority complex, then the answer is most likely "one". If instead of general sentience you mean "human like intelligence" the answer, as above, is almost certainly "one". A human like intelligence is likely to see other intelligences as threats and will likely kill that threat. See [neanderthals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neanderthal).

Answer (score 1):

My guess is **One** - It's bad enough with racism and even football supporters today. Species-ism would kill off all but one of the species before there was any modern concept of liberalism. This would happen as soon as they came across each other.  Either they would be competing for food (both hunter gatherers) and would go to war, or they would be different - one hunter-gatherer the other prey. In the latter case, the intelligent hunters would wipe out the intelligent prey or at best farm them. Maybe they would keep some as pets - probably bred not to be *too* intelligent.